# Suggestions for Asp.net mvc\Entity framework development tools?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on a project to convert an old asp.net application to asp.net mvc\Entity framework.  I'm at the very beginning of the planning stage and I've been asked if I need any software tools so they can budget for them.   I've already got Visual Studio and a Telerik license.  Any other suggestions that might be valuable from UI components to profiling tools?  I'm especially looking for anything that might speed up development.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) will make you much more productive in VS if you learn the key combos.  It will also highlight errors in your views at dev time, rather than waiting for them to show up at runtime, which is very helpful.

[EFProf](http://efprof.com/) will help you tune your EF queries and see what's going on "under the covers"